# Yii validation rules for foreign key

Tags: php, validation, yii, yii-components

Let's say I have an ActiveRecord with the following validation rules:

```
public function rules() {
    return array(
        array('model', 'required'),
        // ....
        array('model', 'exist',
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'attributeName' => 'id',
            'className' => 'Model',
            'message' => 'The specified model does not exist.'
        )
    );
}
```

The first rule forces the `model` field not to be blank, the second one checks it has a consistent value (`model` is a foreign key).

If I try to validate a form in which I leave empty the field `model` I get 2 errors, one for  the first rule and one for the second rule.

I would like to receive only the "*cannot be blank*" error message.

Is there a way to stop the validation when the first rule is not satisfied?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`skipOnError`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CValidator#skipOnError-detail):

```
return array(
    array('model', 'required'),
    // ....
    array('model', 'exist',
        'allowEmpty' => false,
        'attributeName' => 'id',
        'className' => 'Model',
        'message' => 'The specified model does not exist.',
        'skipOnError'=>true
    )
);
```

Edit:

Someone commented about the above being not clear, probably because the *field name* here is also `model`. So keep that in mind when implementing.